# $$haskey gets deleted after using 'orderBy'

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularjs-orderby

This is an element in my array that I am getting from firebase:

```
{
    $$hashKey : "object:7",
    $id : "-KiLvF6Pq_2WCOyCyZPK",
    $priority : null,
    category : 1,
    color : "#D83233",
    complexity : 4,
    name : "new task",
    priority : 6,
    series : 0,
    shape : "circle",
    x : 4,
    y : 6
}
```

& when I use `$filter('orderBy')($scope.tasks,'category');` I get the same array but without the `$$hashkey` which breaks other functionalities.

Is that a bug? Is there a way around it?

Comment: Do you have other logic pivoting off $$hashKey?

Comment: @MathewBerg yes when it's gone this `$scope.tasks.$save(task);` causes an error `undefined function $save`

Comment: Can you post more of your code?